# Appending the html with quotes in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm appending some HTML tags when a user clicks on "like" in feeds section of my website. But it is breaking. I tried with lot of solutions available on the web, but I could not find the solution.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$('#feed20').find('strong')
.append('<span original-title="<ul><li>
<a href="http://localhost/forex/profile/username">username</a>
</li></ul>" custom-style="view-more" class="tiply_html_click">1 more</span>');
```

Comment: What's your HTML, what's your input and what do you want the output to be? And you can't contain a `ul` within a `span`, that'd be invalid HTML.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Here i don't want any valid html. I need to safely insert them into the strong tag.

Comment: You expressly want to use invalid HTML? Because that'll probably, and unpredictably, mess your JavaScript up somewhat.

Comment: @DavidThomas No but the valid html is not the problem here. But appending it into the content is the problem

Comment: How can you append invalid html... the invalid html is just ignored or replaced with something else by the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes, try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDLyW/)

```
$("#feed20").find("strong").append("<span original-title=\"<ul><li><a href='http://localhost/forex/profile/username'>username</a></li></ul>\" custom-style=\"view-more\" class=\"tiply_html_click\">1 more</span>");
```

​

Answer (score 2):

You are having issues with your quotes.  You wrapped a string with double quotes but then used a double quote in the string therefore terminating the string literal.

Try escaping the internal double quotes (`\"`) like this -

```
'<span original-title="<ul><li><a href=\"http://localhost/forex/profile/username\">username</a></li></ul>" custom-style="view-more" class="tiply_html_click">1 more</span>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Data in HTML attributes must be htmlentitized, try :

```
$('#feed20').find('strong').append('<span original-title="&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/forex/profile/username&quot;&gt;username&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;" custom-style="view-more" class="tiply_html_click">1 more</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes that are used in the `<a>` href attribute

```
$('#feed20').find('strong').append('<span original-title="<ul><li><a href=\'http://localhost/forex/profile/username\'>username</a></li></ul>" custom-style="view-more" class="tiply_html_click">1 more</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use escaped single quotes for href.

```
$('#feed20').find('strong').append('<span original-title="<ul><li><a href=\'http://localhost/forex/profile/username\'>username</a></li></ul>" custom-style="view-more" class="tiply_html_click">1 more</span>');
```

Answer (score -2):

From :

**custom-style="view-more" class="tiply_html_click">1 more');**

is wrong...

Comment: The custom-style is also an attribute.

Comment: An explanation would go along way here.  Clearly there is **something** wrong, but helping the OP would include suggesting how to fix the problem...

Comment: @Udhay, I was not suggesting the custom-style was wrong, just pointing to the part of the markup where it was invalid.